# GAE, how to search a text string in datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, jpql, google-cloud-datastore

I have a table with following definition

```
Entity(name = "HistoryVisitsDeviceJPA")
public class HistoryVisitsDeviceJPA {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private Text pageAddress;
        private long date;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            HistoryVisitsDeviceJPA that = (HistoryVisitsDeviceJPA) o;

            if (!pageAddress.equals(that.pageAddress)) return false;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return pageAddress.hashCode();
        }

    // Other setter and getter methods
    }
```

I've stored url in `pageAddress` filed and it's time stamp in `date` field.
I want to search in all records based on `pageAddress` and pull list of matched objects.

My query is like this:

```
private static final String QUERY_HISTORY_VISITS = "SELECT m FROM HistoryVisitsDeviceJPA m WHERE m.pageAddress LIKE :keyword";

try {
                System.out.println("1");
                Query q = em.createQuery(QUERY_HISTORY_VISITS).setParameter("keyword", urlParam);

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<HistoryVisitsDeviceJPA> dbList = (List<HistoryVisitsDeviceJPA>) q.getResultList();
                String jsonString = printJson_HistoryVisitsDeviceJPA(dbList);
                if(jsonString != null) {
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    out.println(jsonString);
                }
            } finally {
                if (em != null)
                    em.close();
            }
```

When I run the application, I'm getting following error:

```
Problem with query <SELECT FROM HistoryVisitsDeviceJPA m WHERE m.pageAddress LIKE :keyword>: Wildcard must appear at the end of the expression string (only prefix matches are supported)
```

I tried to add '%' at the end of string but I was not successful. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the static final string QUERY_HISTORY_VISITS as shown and change

```
setParameter("keyword", urlParam);
```

to

```
setParameter("keyword", urlParam+"%");
```

assuming that is consistent with your program logic.